# How to connect to vmware ESXi remote console

Tags: console, vmware, rdp, esxi

I need to know what is the protocol used in vmware ESXi vSphere client to connect to the remote console?
Is this protocol open source ?
Is their any vmware/third party applications enables VM Remote console connection other than vsphere client ?

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking to connect to a ESX machine, without the heavy overhead of the vSphere client then you can use the VMware Remote Console.

While this isn't *formally* documented, one of the developers has kindly posted some fairly detailed information on the VMware Forums.

- [vmware-vmrc.exe command documentation](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/156057?tstart=0)

Depending what version of the plugin or vSphere client you have installed depends on the exact location of the plugin. Here is an example for what I have installed as part of vShpere 5

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\VMware\
VMware VMRC Plug-in\Internet Explorer\vmware-vmrc.exe"
-u user -p password -h esxi.localnet -d "[store1] Test/Test.vmx"
```

Answer (score 3):

VMware's console access is indeed a closed protocol. However, they do have an embeddable web control called the Remote Console that implements this. It is an 'experimental' feature I believe, and won't be supported by them. But it's doable.

So while the protocol isn't implemented by anyone else I know of, there is an option to wrap the control at least.

See: [Installing and Using the VMware Remote Console Plug-in](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Using_the_VMware_Remote_Console_Plug-in)